# "NoClassDefFoundError" in Velocity

Tags: java, velocity

I use Velocity in Java project to generate source code. I export the project as jar file to use it in an other project.
 This is my velocity properties file content:
runtime.log.logsystem.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.SystemLogChute
resource.loader = resources/
classpath.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
I get this error:
Internal compiler error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/exception/ResourceNotFoundException at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

That Class was present during build time but it depends upon environment, if you are working in J2EE environment than you can get NoClassDefFoundError even if class is present because it may not be visible to corresponding class loader.

Put all dependencies to `WEB-INF/lib` and add them to `CLASSPATH`.

> Where to Put the Velocity Jar

```
First of all you have to decide whether you will use the dependency-free version 
 of velocity.jar or the version including all dependend jars. If you are not worried 
about collisions with Avalon Logkit, Commons Collections or Jakarta Oro, using the jar 
containing all dependencies is very convenient.

Putting the velocity jar in WEB-INF/lib your web application 
will result in it's classes being available in the classpath for that web application.
```